# TypeError: Cannot assign read only property 'delegatedHandlers' of aurelia-dom-boundary

Tags: aurelia

I've been working on modifying the Aurelia skeleton app, and things have been going along fine. Then I added in two new jspm dependencies, bootstrap-material and aurelia-validation.  Once I did that, I started getting the following two errors.

```
ERROR [app-router] TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'delegatedHandlers' of aurelia-dom-boundary
ERROR [app-router] Router navigation failed, and no previous location could be restored.
```

I cannot get past this. I've tried removing those dependencies, reverting things back to when they were working and I still get the errors.  Any idea what could be causing it?

Comment: further debugging, I found that if I remove my click.delegate from my form submit button, the error goes away.  However that delegate was working just fine before I added the new dependencies.  Changing click.delegate="login()" to click.trigger="login()" fixes the error.  What is the underlying problem here? why can't I use delegate now?

Comment: I have no idea why this is happening, but only passing to say that you should should use the <form> tag with submit.delegate(), if you have a submit button. It's a better convention. About the error, maybe you should throw it at github.com/aurelia-framework issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is just a regression in Aurelia binding library caused by this commit: https://github.com/aurelia/binding/commit/8d33813eb340c2136198916a4a757a2c577f5aab

```
let boundary = target.domBoundary || document,
    delegatedHandlers = boundary.delegatedHandlers || (boundary.delegatedHandlers = {}),
    ...
```

I have made a comment, but did not open an Issue.

I rolled back the binding library from 0.8.4 to 0.8.2 until a fix is released.

Edit: they have fixed the issue

Comment: Looks like the issue has been fixed, so rolling forward/updating all Aurelia packages should get you in a stable state.